# How to make an image change when a .slideToggle() go up and down

Tags: jquery, image, show-hide

My code for my website doesn't work here is the link to the fiddle:

*NOTE* JSFiddle updated for anyone who needs help...

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thakyZ/jBvSt/3/)

If I click the image it changes but it doesn't change back...
Line 39 adds the image:

```
$("#sel" + i).prepend("<img id='ico" + i + "' src='https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5z6muxkoq2ort9l/arrowside.png' width='24' height='24' /> ");
```

Comment: "And if I make it so if I make the div id #sel1 only open then it works but the image doesn't." unclear what you want here mate

Comment: so if I make it so I click on the whole box then it opens but not when I click on the image

Comment: I have found out why the button was not activating but I still cant toggle the image

Comment: You had bug on line 12 of the javascript that was causing no script to load.  Was that the issue you were referring to?

Comment: No... That is not what I was getting at...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are binding the click events to elements before they exist.  You could either move your for loop above the event bind statements, or group them in a function that you can call after the rest of your script runs.  See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/TPcHp/

```
function bindClicks()
{
    $("#ico1").click(function()
    {
       //Rest of your code here
    }
    //More click binding fun
}

for (var i = 1; i < recipes.length + 1; i++)
    {
        $("#sel" + i).attr("data-hidden", i);
        $("#sel" + i).prepend("<img id='ico" + i + "' src='https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5z6muxkoq2ort9l/arrowside.png' width='24' height='24' /> ");
        $("#ico" + i).attr("data-hidden", i);            
    }

bindClicks();
```

You also had a bug on line 12 of your jsfiddle that was causing the javascript to not run.  Notice the apostrophe at the end of the line

```
$('.info:not(#res' + hiddenid + ')').slideUp();'
```

To fix your toggle issue, try testing to see if the element is hidden before calling the slideToggle (as this will be mid transition): http://jsfiddle.net/ypAC9/

```
$("#ico1").click(function()
    {        
        var hiddenid = $(this).data('hidden');
        if ($("#res" + hiddenid).is(":visible"))
        {
            $(this).attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/5z6muxkoq2ort9l/arrowside.png");
        }
        else
        {
            $(this).attr("src", "https://dl.dropbox.com/s/hf4i6ww9xvemlc4/arrowdown.png");
        }

        $('#res' + hiddenid).slideToggle();
        $('.info:not(#res' + hiddenid + ')').slideUp();

    });
```

Comment: I already solved that issue 5 mins ago but I was wondering how to change the icon when it opens and closes...